# Can I use audio-service on Android without renaming main acitivty?

Tags: android, audio-service

I'm using a maps API in my project, which needs to be initialised within MainActivity, and when it's renamed in the manifest file, the maps will not work.

This is my MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey([key])
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

Comment: The name of an activity has 0 effect of what you can do within it.  There is 0 chance that the maps API is requiring a particular activity name.  You're doing something else wrong.

Comment: @GabeSechan well I'm afraid the kotlin code in MainActivity file doesn't work after renaming the class in the manifest file, because, as mentioned, maps don't start

Comment: Post your code, we have no idea what you're doing wrong without that.   But I can tell you that it is definitely not a requirement to use a certain activity name, very few large scale apps have an activity named MainActivity.  That's kind of what you do for a school project, not a serious app.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok, added the code. All of this is required according to the docs of Yandex Mapkit

Comment: When their docs say main activity, they don't mean an activity named MainActivity.  They mean it as a concept-  the first activity you display (after splash screen and login).

Comment: @GabeSechan Okaaay, then if it was renamed to `com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity` in the manifest, what should be done next?

Comment: The matching. changes need to be made to the package name and the name of the Java class, in order for Android to find everything.  The manifest does need to match the Java.

Comment: @GabeSechan Excuse me for delay, but I can't figure out what should my main activity be called after this. I tried AudioServiceActivity, if that's what's needed.
I just really can't comprehend how all this activity thing works

Comment: AN activity can be called anything you want.  The only catch is that activities need to be listed in the Manifest, and their name there needs to match the name of the Activity.  In the manifest tag, there is a package attribute.  It needs to be the full package you want to use on the app store (for example com.example.MyApp). Then in the application tag you have a tag for each activity.  The name parameter on the activity must be either the fully qualified name (com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity) or a name relative to the package of the manifest (.AudioServiceActivity).

Comment: That's the only link where the name matters.  In the Java or Kotlin code, the name will not matter whatsoever.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay, thanks for the explanation, but frankly, this all seems just like the rephrasing of what you said in previous comments. So what's actually going on on my end: the audio-service docs tells me to rename android:name of existing activity to that string - that's done. Then, if you say that the name of my main activity class in kotlin file has no effect in the project as a whole (if I understand you correctly), then the file remains intact, correct?

Comment: Joining this thread, as I have the same issue. @GabeSechan, can you please elaborate, if `android:name` of the activity in the `AndroidManifest` file is renamed to `com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity`, what other steps should be taken so that the initializations previously done by `MainActivity` will still occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to change your Launcher activity in android manifest. But just update your Main Activity with this overridden function

Kotlin:

```
override fun provideFlutterEngine(context:Context):FlutterEngine {
            return AudioServicePlugin.getFlutterEngine(context);
}
```

Java:

```
@Override
public FlutterEngine provideFlutterEngine(Context context) {
        return AudioServicePlugin.getFlutterEngine(context);
}
```